# Does a convergent subsequence in $W^{1,2}$ implies the convergence of the whole sequence

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Define $f: [0,\infty)\times \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Suppose $f(t,\cdot)\in W^{1,2}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for all $t$ and $f(t,x)$ converges to $g(x)$ in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ as $t\rightarrow \infty$. Besides, there exists a sequence ${t_i}$ such that $f(t_i,x)$ converges to $g(x)$ in $W^{1,2}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Can we prove $f(t,x)$ converges to $g(x)$ in $W^{1,2}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ as $t\rightarrow \infty$? Or what conditions do we need further?

Comment: We need something that implies that $\bigl(f(t,\,\cdot\,)\bigr)_{t\in [0,\infty)}$ is a Cauchy net in $W^{1,2}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Does any boundedness of $f(t,x)$ help?

Comment: It would probably help, but not suffice. So far, we don't even have enough to say that $f(t,\,\cdot\,)$ belongs to $W^{1,2}$ for all $t$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Let's suppose $f(t,x)$ belongs to $W^{1,2}$ for all $t$.

Comment: Still, we need more. Let $n = 1$ and $h_k(x) = \chi_{[-\pi,\pi]}(x)\sin (kx)$ for $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and $g_k(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x h_k(y)\,dy$. With $f(t,x) = g_{\lfloor t+1\rfloor}(x)\cdot \sin t$, we have a bounded family in $W^{1,2}$ such that $f(t,x) \to 0$ in $L^2$ and $f(m\pi,x) \to 0$ in $W^{1,2}$, but $f(t,x)$ doesn't converge in $W^{1,2}$.